# Avoid indirection and redundant method calls

Tags: java, android

I am currently reviewing a PullRequest that contains this:

```
-        for (int i = 0; i < outgoingMassages.size(); i++) {
+        for (int i = 0, size = outgoingMassages.size(); i < size; i++)
```

https://github.com/criticalmaps/criticalmaps-android/pull/52

somehow it feels wrong to me - would think that the vm is doing these optimisations - but cannot really say for sure. Would love to get some input if this change can make sense - or a confirmation that this is done on VM-side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, is not sure that the VM will change your code from

```
 -        for (int i = 0; i < outgoingMassages.size(); i++) {
```

to

```
 +        for (int i = 0, size = outgoingMassages.size(); i < size; i++)
```

In your for loop it is possible that the `outgoingMassages` will change its size. So This optimization can't be applied by the JVM. Also another thread can change the `outgoingMassages` size if this is a shared resource.

The JVM can change the code only if the behaviour doesn't change. For example it can substitute a list of string concatenations with a sequence of append to `StringBuilder`, or it can inline a simple method call, or can calculate a value out of the loop if it is a constant value.

Comment: What if we know that `outgoingMassages.size()` will not be changed? Isn't it will be optimized, because we don't need to call the object `outgoingMassages` and method `size()` everytime?

Comment: @HendraWD if you know that the size of outgoingMessages is not changed  during the loop assigning the size to a variable is an optimization that can be done. However, generally,  it is better to concentrate on how to reduce time in the code inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The VM will not do this optimizations. Since it is possible that the size()-Method does not return the same result each call. So the method must be called each iteration.

However if size is a simple getter-method the performance impact is very small. Probably not measurable. (In few cases it may enable Java to use parallelization which could make a difference then, but this depends on the content of the loop).

The bigger difference may be to ensure that the for-loop has an amount of iterations which is known in advance. It doesn't seem make sense to me in this example. But maybe the called method could return changing results which are unwanted?

Answer (score 0):

If the `size()` method on your collection is just giving the value of a private field, then the VM will optimise most of this away (but not quite all). It'll do it by inlining the `size()` method, so that it just becomes access to that field.

The remaining bit that won't get optimised is that `size` in the new code will get treated as `final`, and therefore constant, whereas the field picked up from the collection won't be treated as `final` (perhaps it's modified from another thread). So in the original case the field will get read in every iteration, but in the new case it won't.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that any decent optimiser - either at the VM or in the compiler - will recognise:

```
class Messages {

    int size;

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }
}

public void test() {
    Messages outgoingMassages = new Messages();
    for (int i = 0; i < outgoingMassages.size(); i++) {

    }
}
```

and optimise it to

```
    for (int i = 0; i < outgoingMassages.size; i++) {
```

doing the extra - untested - optimisation should therefore be considered [evil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).

Answer (score 0):

The method invocation will happen on **each** iteration of the loop and is **not free** of costs. Since you cannot predict how often this happens calling it **once** will always be **less**. It is a minor optimization but you should not rely on the compiler to do the optimization for you.

Further, the member `outgoingMassages` ..

```
private ArrayList<OutgoingChatMessage> outgoingMassages ..
```

... should be an interface:

```
private List<OutgoingChatMessage> outgoingMassages ..
```

Then, calling `.size()` will become a virtual method. To find out the specific object class the method table will be invoked for all classes of the hierarchy. This is not free of costs again.